# Which ZeroMQ socket is recommended for this scenario?

Tags: message-queue, zeromq, netmq

We are building an online game(browser based) platform on top of WebApi and SignalR. One of our top priority is low latency response times and scalability. In terms of scalability, we are considering scaleout method, to distribute application load across several server nodes. However, this architecture doesn't come without additional complexities.

Let me describe the problem before I ask my question. Consider we have 2 server nodes for load balancing purpose. And we have say 50,000 players online. 50% of players are connected to Node1 and another 50% to Node2 using SignalR/Websockets. Now the problem arises when Node1 needs to deliver a message to a player which is connected to Node2. There's no physical connection between Node1 and the player.

So now we have 2 possible solution:

1. Force a group of similar players to join the same node. However, this approach posed more problems than it fixed (especially during failover recovery), for our scenario. I won't go into details.
2. Allow nodes to communicate each other, so when node1 needs to send a message to a client connected to node2, node1 will do it with the help of node2 (something like node1 --> node2 --> client). In this scenario, every node will be connected to every other node.

As you might've guessed, we chose second solution. As I already mentioned, server response time should be very low, sub 50ms max, so adding additional communication layer on top of server side is a problem. Server communication should be as efficient as possible.

That's why we decided to use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). We tested it (REQ-REP) and performance is way more than our acceptable margin. But there's a catch. I have read the [documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-socket) several times but it confused me more than gave me ideas. In short, I have no idea which socket type to use in my scenario. I don't need queuing messages if a node goes offline, just to ignore it.

So any recommendation/help would be nice. Also, if someone could find time to describe shortly why a particular socket/pattern is a better approach for us would be even nicer :)

Comment: Read [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), that will do far more for your understanding than the man pages.  Make sure you get through at least chapter 5, don't skip out early just because you think you've solved your particular question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to allow for each client (player) to have a Router socket with the Identity of the socket being the identity of the player to allow for communication between the node and the player.  You could then use some the broker patterns available on [0MQ - The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) to support what you are going for.  The router socket documentation is also available via the link.

An example would be to have each node act as broker allowing clients to send requests to them and if they know that the requested client resides on that node they will service the request, otherwise they will broadcast it to the other nodes.